# Ajax postback resets tab index -1

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

After postback from Modal Popup Extender all controls tab index set to -1, i am not able to find any solution for this, And there are more than 100 controls in my page.

How i can keep the Tab Index of all my controls in ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 2):

Check your calls to .Show() for the modal popup extender.  When you call .Show() it stores all the TabIndexes for your controls to a variable.  It does this so it can prevent your controls from being in the tab order while the MPE is shown.  If you call .Show() while the MPE is already shown (and has already modified the TabIndexes) it will store the -1's over top of the previous values and put them back when the MPE is hidden, thinking it is doing the right thing.