# Tabindex in AJAX modalpopupextender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, tabindex

I have an AJAX ModalPopupExtender and with in it have another ModalPopupExtender. I'm actually about working with tabindex in the child popup. when the parent popup is displayed, tabindex works fine and when displayed child popup with in parent (using link button click), tabindex doesn;t work.. Is any one aware of this issue previously? Please let me know the solution if yes.

Comment: See this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825899/ajax-postback-resets-tab-index-1